# How to Resolve Precision Error in Accessing prewritten data on a .h5 file (Python)

Tags: types, attributes, precision, h5py

I am trying to access data from a public dataset that was uploaded in sets of batches. Each batch is a large .h5 file that contains several images. These images have attributes that tell me the settings that were used to create these image simulations. Below is the code I'm running to access a specific group's attributes, but occasionally I come across a precision error that I have no idea how to resolve. I've tried changing the data type using `astype(np.int64)` but there is a problem with accessing that attribute data in the first place. These attributes are numerical values that were saved with high precision at the time by the owners of the dataset (8 decimal places).

This is the code I use to get a specific group and access the attributes individually:

```
keys = list(f.keys())
key = keys[0]
group = f[key]
print(key)
print(group.attrs.keys())
print(group.attrs['space_group'])
print(group.attrs['formula'])
print(group.attrs['z_dirs'])
print(group.attrs['y_dirs'])
print(group.attrs['semi_angles_rad'])
```

...And here is the error message I receieve:

```
sample_10_0
<KeysViewHDF5 ['abc_angstrom', 'angles_degree', 'd_hkls_angstrom', 'energy_keV', 'formula', 'material', 'semi_angles_rad', 'space_group', 'y_dirs', 'z_dirs']>
b'9'
Li6 Cu6 P6 O24
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 0  1 -1]
  [ 2 -2  0]]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9836/1283281529.py in <module>
      7 print(group.attrs['formula'])
      8 print(group.attrs['z_dirs'])
----> 9 print(group.attrs['y_dirs'])
     10 print(group.attrs['semi_angles_rad'])

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

D:\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\attrs.py in __getitem__(self, name)
     59             return Empty(attr.dtype)
     60 
---> 61         dtype = attr.dtype
     62         shape = attr.shape
     63 

h5py\h5a.pyx in h5py.h5a.AttrID.dtype.__get__()

h5py\h5a.pyx in h5py.h5a.AttrID.dtype.__get__()

h5py\h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.TypeFloatID.py_dtype()

ValueError: Insufficient precision in available types to represent (63, 52, 11, 0, 52)
```

If anyone has any idea how to change the data type of the values or make it so I can access the original values with the same precision, that would be great. I actually need these original values kept as is, up to 5 decimal places ideally (could go down to 4 if needed)

Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem... I have never gotten an "Insufficient precision" error, so this is my best guess to diagnose the issue. I suspect the error is converting the attribute value to the string needed for the print statement. The attribute may be saved as an unexpected data type and may require some wrangling to print.

First, I would check attribute `semi_angles_rad` to be sure you can access it.

Next, I would check the type on `y_dirs` like this: `print(type(group.attrs['y_dirs']))`. (Also, I would do the same for `z_dirs` for comparison.) You may also need to check the dtype. Once you have the type, you will be in a better position to figure out the next step.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! When trying to print the data type, it provides the same error. It seems like in trying to check the type, it needs to access the attribute info first, but it clearly can't. When doing so for `z_dirs` , it gives me `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` which I know isn't very helpful. Trying `print(group.attrs['z_dirs'])` alone actually tells me the dtype is int64. I will keep trying to have a go at it in the meantime.

Comment: @Timothy Yoo, I was afraid that might happen. Ugh. What version of h5py are you using? Also what is the HDF5 version of the file? The HDF Group has tools to inspect the file. I suggest **HDF View** -- it's a graphical viewer that will let you "see" the data structure, values, and types. You can also use **h5dump** -- it is a command line utility to do the same thing.

Comment: I got HDF view and it looks handy. The datatype contained in the attributes that I cannot access are 128-bit floats and the ones I can access are 64-bit integer. I would assume that the problem lies in lack of support for 128-bit values. I am not sure how these values were written to the dataset in the first place if this is the case. I am not exactly sure the version of the file, but under "library version bounds" it states "Earliest and V110". The h5py version is the latest, 3.6.0, with python 3.9.7. I do know, however, that this dataset was made with one of the earliest versions of h5py.

Comment: Ok, now we are getting somewhere. h5py now supports 16 byte (128 bit) floats (at least for datasets). But older versions did not, and required some low level trickery to implement. Here is an old h5py forum post with details: [numpy float128](https://groups.google.com/g/h5py/c/HHfoljlfUu8)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example that confirms a current version of h5py (3.7) can create a `np.float128` attribute and read the value.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
print(h5py.__version__)
with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w') as f:
    # This creates 2 attributes of different types:
    f.attrs['as_float64'] = 1.0
    print(type(f.attrs['as_float64']))
    f.attrs['as_float128'] = np.float128(2.0)
    print(type(f.attrs['as_float128']))
```

**Update 2022-08-03**: shows how to use the low level API to access attribute to get float128 value.

```
with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w') as f:
    # This creates 2 attributes of arrays of different np.float types:
    arr_in = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])
    f.attrs['as_float64'] = arr_in
    arr_in.dtype = np.float128
    f.attrs['as_float128'] = arr_in
with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r') as f:
    # get attribute arrays with with high level API: 
    print(type(f.attrs['as_float64']))
    print(type(f.attrs['as_float128']))
    # get float128 attribute array with with low level API: 
    aid = f.attrs.get('as_float128')
    print(aid.dtype, aid.shape)
    arr_out = np.empty(shape=aid.shape,dytpe=aid.dtype)
    aid.read(arr.out)
    print(arr_out)
```

Comment: @Timothy Yoo see update that shows how to read attributes with the low level API.